# Module based system in PHP - how to?

Tags: php, class, module

I have a PHP web application where I've made a little module system, that basically works like this:

Each module has it's own file, filename can be anything, but does not matter (for the sake of logic I named the filename is the same as the module name). The content of a module could look like this:

```
$MODULE["name"] = "some_module";
$MODULE["description"] = "This module does some things";
$MODULE["required"] = false;
$MODULE["module_specific_var"] = some_function_that_returns_some_value();
```

I have a global $MODULES array where I read all modules into:

```
foreach ($modules_list as $module_filename){
  if (isset($MODULE)) unset($MODULE);
  include($module_path."/".$module_filename);
  $MODULES[$MODULE["name"]] = $MODULE;
}
```

Now this is pretty simple and have been more than enough for my needs... Until now... Now I need a module specific function and that doesn't work with associative arrays (as far as I know of). What I'd like is something along the lines of being able to call `$MODULES["name_of_module"]["name_of_module_specific_function"]();`

I know this can be achieved with function references and as long as I use `include()` for each module, any functions defined in the module files will be available in global space - this may cause naming issues though, so bad idea.

Alternatively I make each module a class, something along the lines of:

```
class module_name {
  var $name = "some_module";
  var $description = "This module does some things";
  var $required = false;
  var $module_specific_var = some_function_that_returns_some_value();
  function module_specific_function(){
  }
}
```

Since I've already got a fair bit of code, my question is - is there an alternative to making all the modules class based, which avoids both the problem of name conflicts and allows me to keep the current module system fairly intact?

Comment: you shouldn't rely on globals variable http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: So, you want to encapsulate data and methods in a structure of some kind.. Sort of like an "object", if you may.. Now what PHP5 feature could you use for that.. Hmmm.. tricky!

Comment: Well, if I were you I would rewrite that module-oriented architecture to be object-oriented. One problem of your approach you already named = name collisions and overpopulated global scope. You can defer the problem by using namespaces (new in PHP 5.3), but that will not solve it.

Comment: what are you requirement that impose you to rewrite it ?

Comment: Plain laziness :P Just wanted to check if there were other ways before rewriting the code.

Comment: Btw, Marek Sebera I don't exactly see what the security issue is here - I don't have register_globals = on, I only define variables in global scope and use the $GLOBALS array subsequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OO is the way to go here. Make a `Module` base class, and extend that if you need module specific functions.

If you map the class names to your file names, you can even use an autoloader so you won't have to `include()` everything. It would also be nice to have a central [Singleton](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) class to keep track of your module instances (to avoid having to use globals, which is a deprecated practice).

Comment: That's not a module system, that's just extending some base class. I think something like CommonJS or ES6 Modules (for JavaScript) but done in PHP would be the way to go! Ideas like these: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/commonjs/sVkxbQtR-lw

Answer (score 1):

I think something like CommonJS or ES6 Modules for PHP would be nice. Already some ideas on that: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/commonjs/sVkxbQtR-lw

Answer (score 0):

1. Modules system  based on plain functions is hardly maintinable - use objects
2. PHP since version 5 can autoload module by its name
3. Use hierarchical system - from abstract module or interface, you will know what this module can do.
4. If you have name in variable you can create instance like this - `$foo = new $bar()`

where $foo is new instance and $bar stores object name

Comment: 1. No, it doesn't. It depends on the each project. Using OOP without knowing what you're doing is bad.